# Ubuntu certbot Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80

Tags: networking, server, apache2, ssl, certificates

I've created a config file for site in /etc/apache2/sites-available/, enabled it and restarted apache. `sudo apache2ctl configtest`  shows `Syntax OK`. When I execute `sudo certbot --apache` - I cannot see my domain and if I execute `sudo certbot --apache -d csgo.sbs` - It responds:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator apache, Installer apache
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for csgo.sbs
Cleaning up challenges
Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80.
```

My config sites-enabled config:

```
# csgo.sbs
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/home/csgo.sbs"
    ServerName csgo.sbs
    ServerAlias www.csgo.sbs
    ErrorLog "logs/csgo.sbs-error_log.log"
    CustomLog "logs/csgo.sbs-access_log.log" common
    <Directory "/home/csgo.sbs">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Depending on how you configured Apache, I can see there may be issues with the `DocumentRoot`, as it's outside the `/var/www` directory. Were you able to access the site before trying to create the SSL certificate? Have you checked the `letsencrypt.log` file as well as the access and error logs on `/var/log/apache2`? 

Comment: @matigo tried to create site in `/var/www` and it's not working too. No, I wasn't able to access site before SSL, I thought that I would after I create a certificate

Comment: Have you confirmed that `ufw` is allowing traffic to reach Apache?